# Why am I getting an ferror on my source file using zlib deflate?

Tags: c, debugging, file, compression, zlib

**EDIT**

```
  // open output file for writing
  if ( ( outfilefd = fopen( file_name, "w+t" ) ) == NULL )
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create file\n");
      exit(1);
    }
```

Write to the file, then need to zip it.

Opening a .z file and then calling def()

```
FILE *zipFile;

   if ( ( zipFile = fopen( "C:\\LOGS\\test.txt.z", "w+t" ) ) == NULL )
   {
         fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create file\n");
         exit(1);
   }



   int ret = def(outfilefd, zipFile, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
        if (ret != Z_OK)
            printf("ZLIB Error");
```

using def(), right from the [site](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html):

```
 int def(FILE *source, FILE *dest, int level)
    {
        int ret, flush;
        unsigned have;
        z_stream strm;
        unsigned char in[CHUNK];
        unsigned char out[CHUNK];

        /* allocate deflate state */
        strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
        strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
        strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
        ret = deflateInit(&strm, level);
        if (ret != Z_OK)
            return ret;

        /* compress until end of file */
        do {

            strm.avail_in = fread(in, 1, CHUNK, source);
      int g = ferror(source);//<---------------- EROR HERE returning 32?
            if (ferror(source)) {
                (void)deflateEnd(&strm);
                return Z_ERRNO;
            }
```

`zipFile` is not null, `strm.avail_in` = 16343, `in` has the data but `ferror(source)` returns 32?

**EDIT** - Also `strm.avail_in` = 16343 caught my eye as `CHUNK` = 16384....is that OK?

Any ideas or help is appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: I don't know what 32 is.  Try [perror](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/perror.html) to print the error text.

Comment: What's the meaning of errno 32 on your platform, could you perror("") it? On linux it says broken pipe, which sounds odd considering you opened a file.

Comment: maybe just show how you open the source, it's your problem so why should we assume or guess?

Comment: `strm.avail_in` = 16343 probably just means that the filesize of the source file modulo 16384 is 16343.

Comment: I needed to rewind the pointer to the file, it was pointing to the end!

Answer (score 2):

You should open the file in binary mode instead of text mode:

```
zipFile = fopen( "C:\\LOGS\\test.txt.z", "w+b" )
```

Comment: Your variable names are a bit confusing, `outfilefd` is actually the input file - what mode have you opened that in ?